# Simple SQL questions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL, and I am answering some questions in the book but I couldn't find the answers can someone please help me with this

the question is

Given a database table 'names' composed of two columns 'id' and 'name', what query will find the duplicate names?

```
SELECT * FROM names GROUP BY name WHERE id > 1;
SELECT * FROM names n1 LEFT JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name;
SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;
SELECT * FROM names n1 LEFT JOIN names n2 ON n1.id != n2.id;
```

Comment: Why can't you just create a temporary table and test this yourself?

Comment: You can use the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to create your database on the fly and test it.

Comment: Or probably you should read a tutorial. For example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Otherwise neither solution is perfect... The only solution which will show the duplicates will multiply them by the number of repetitions.

Comment: Third one......

Answer (score 3):

This would show you all names occurring more than once:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), Name FROM names GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Number 1 is not a valid query. GROUP BY requires some aggregate function to be in the query, and all other columns you do not wish to aggregate have to be listed in the GROUP BY. The `WHERE ID > 1` part would just dismiss the record with `id 1`, but does little more than that.

Number 2 would not work either. It'd simply produce a list with all accounts listed twice in the same row.

Number 4 would give you something almost identical to a `cross join`.

Number 3 would actually do the trick, albeit in a not-so-efficient way. It basically joins the table on itself, using the name as a `JOIN` operator, and then uses the `WHERE n1.id != n2.id` clause to ensure that if a name exists more than once, it will not join the row on itself. Thus, it gives you a list of all duplicate names.

The reason it's not very efficient is that in case you have 1 name that exists dozens of times, you'd still end up with a lot of rows in the result, and you'd still now be able to easily see only the names that exist more than once. On a million row table, it could also take a substantial amount of time to run the query, as you're basically using a character field for a `JOIN` (which is not very efficient).

Comment: The answer that the poster is looking for is in one of the select statements they presented.

Comment: @Linger I just edited in the individual queries and their answers. I still think that even though #3 would do the trick, it's not an efficient method.

Comment: *@SchmitzIT*, While there are several ways the result could be obtained, the OP only wanted the correct answer amongst a predefined list.  Just saying option 3 would work does not explain why it would work.  If you expand on why option 3 is the correct answer with samples and explanations of what each piece of the query actually means, would help the user more then just saying it would work.

Comment: @Linger - Thanks :) +1 for helping me be a better contributor.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;
```

This statement is your answer..Because:
Imagine you have a table name: names
Its has two column Id and name. Firstly this queries select all data from names table then it compare itself name=name and if id !=id. At last it returns desired result..

Comment: Given those 4 choices, this one is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one is your answer.

```
SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The third one is your answer

```
SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;
```

It says, select all from the table `names` where, if compared to itself, the names are the same but the ids are not.

With the table Below:

```
1 Bob 
2 Bob
3 George
```

It would show:

```
1 Bob 2 Bob
2 Bob 1 Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select names, Count(names) as Duplicate_count 
from names
group by names
having count(names) > 1**
```

With the table Below:

```
id  names

1   Sample1

2   Sample2

3   Sample1

4   Sample2

5   Sample3
```

It would show:

```
names    Duplicate_count

Sample1  2

Sample2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not care whether the result of the query has duplicated data and "id" column is unique then

`SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;`

is the correct answer.

By I saying duplication I mean, multiple records than what is really stored in the table. For example, if you have more than two records with name as "John" but different "id" then the query will return multiple records than what is actually stored.

If the "id" is not a unique column then there is no correct answer from the options provided. Because even the above query (option 3 won't return any records for multiple similar rows of data,  where id and name are similar, this condition will eliminate them out `AND n1.id != n2.id`) The correct answer is

`SELECT count(1) as count, name FROM names group by name having count(1) > 1;`

You can quickly learn SQL from the following link.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp
They already have a database and an environment to try the queries. You can even edit them. Then run them to verify your queries using the "Try it yourself>>" button.

If you do this by practising on your database you can see a lot of variations on how the data is returned when you create more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM names n1 JOIN names n2 ON n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id != n2.id;
```

This should give you the duplicate names. As you're comparing with name and id, which do not match with the ID and matches with the name, it means that the same name has different IDs.

So this query should give you the duplicate names.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select name 
from names 
group by 1 
having count(name) > 1;
```

This would group the name column and whose count is greater than 1 would be extracted as duplicate

Comment: Actually this worked fine for me in sql. Or else  even this would work:                                                                     select name from names group by name having count(name) > 1;